Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission in a Thread class
I m building an Android application that use bluetooth to connenct on third device.
In my project I try to connect on device in a thread class like this:
public class BTClient extends Thread {
    UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000");

    private BluetoothAdapter _adapter;

    private BluetoothSocket _btStream;
    private String _connectionString;

    //private OnSocketClosedErrorListener _socketClosedErrorListener;

    private BluetoothDevice _device;

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice() {
        return _device;
    }

    private BTComms _comms;

    public BTComms getComms() {
        return _comms;
    }


    private boolean _isConnected = false;

    public boolean IsConnected() {
        return _isConnected;
    }

    public boolean _isValidBlueToothAddress = false;

    public void IsValidBlueToothAddress() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
            _isValidBlueToothAddress = _adapter.checkBluetoothAddress(_connectionString);
        }
    }

    private Vector<ConnectedListener<BTClient>> eventSubscribers = new Vector<ConnectedListener<BTClient>>();

    /*This is an array of objects that implement the ConnectedListener interface. Right now the only class that
    implements it is ConnectListenerImpl class and it implements the Connected method*/
    private void OnConnected() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        //Create a new  Vector with exactly same elements as eventSubscribers
                Vector<ConnectedListener<BTClient>> handler = (Vector<ConnectedListener<BTClient>>) eventSubscribers.clone();
        Iterator<ConnectedListener<BTClient>> iter = handler.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            iter.next().Connected(new ConnectedEvent<BTClient>(this));
        }
    }

    public void addConnectedEventListener(ConnectedListener<BTClient> listener) {
        eventSubscribers.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeConnectedEventListener(ConnectedListener<BTClient> listener) {
        eventSubscribers.remove(listener);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public BTClient(BluetoothAdapter adapter, String connectionString/*, OnSocketClosedErrorListener listener*/) throws IOException {
       // _socketClosedErrorListener = listener;
        //Initialize the class variables
        _adapter = adapter; //Assign the adaptor
        // Initializing all other variables to null
        _isConnected = false;
        _comms = null;
        _btStream = null;
        _device = null;
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        IsValidBlueToothAddress();
        //Get a device for the given BT MAC address
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
            _device = _adapter.getRemoteDevice(_connectionString);
        }
        /* try {*/
            //Create a Secure RFComm Bluetooth socket for secure outgoing connection with device
            //using a given "UUID--using well known UUID SPP suggested by Android??"

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
            _btStream = _device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        }
        if (_btStream != null) {    //Attempt to connect to a remote device...Needs an exception check here to
                //see if it fails
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
                _btStream.connect();
            }
            _isConnected = true;
            }
        /*} catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Needs to call this to be sure enough to cancel a discovery service
        //since it is heavy weight service
        //if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        _adapter.cancelDiscovery();
        //}
        if (_isConnected)
            StartCommunication();
        else
            System.out.println("Can't connect to the BioHarness.");
    }



    private void StartCommunication() {
        //Create a new commmunication thread and run it
        _comms = new BTComms(_btStream/*, _socketClosedErrorListener*/);
        _comms.start();

        //Calls Connected method which calls ReceivedPacketMethod that prints information on the phone's text box based on the message type
        OnConnected();
    }

    public void Close() {
        if (_btStream != null) {
            try {
                if (_comms != null)
                    _comms.Close();
                if (_btStream != null)
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
                        _btStream.close();
                    }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        _isConnected = false;
        //_btStream = null;
    }
}

Now this code working when I used Android 8, but now I need to use this code in new Android OS so when I try to connect on device, the app return me the following error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
                                                                                                    Process: it.rmountain, PID: 10445
                                                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for android.content.AttributionSource@b09f4322: AdapterService cancelDiscovery
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2426)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2410)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2393)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2335)
                                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy.cancelDiscovery(IBluetooth.java:3192)
                                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery(BluetoothAdapter.java:1876)
                                                                                                        at zephyr.android.BioHarnessBT.BTClient.run(BTClient.java:119)

The line code on BtClient.java is this:
 _adapter.cancelDiscovery();

How can I fixed it?
EDIT
This is my AndroidManifest file
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        tools:ignore="ManifestOrder" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />


did you add the permission to the manifest like it says and ask for the appropriate permissions at runtime?

@tyczj I just edit my question including also AndroidManifest file

BLUETOOTH_SCAN is a dangerous permission. Please post the code where you are requesting it at runtime, in addition to having it in the manifest.

BLUETOOTH_SCAN is now a runtime permission and, as the name suggests, must be requested at runtime.

Add this in your Activity before initializing(using) BTClient object to check if BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission is granted and if not it is to be requested. Once the code is executed, a system dialog asking the user for permission with "Allow" and "Deny" buttons will be displayed.
private final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_SCAN = 2
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN}, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
                return;
            }

The callback function
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) 

will be triggered when you allow or deny the requested permission.
grantResults will be -1 (PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) if you deny the permission and 0 (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) if you grant the permission.
Once the permission is successfully granted you can initialize(use) BTClient object
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_SCAN){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    // Init BTClient object here
                else
                    // Show a rationale or request again
        }
    }

NB: You can only request the permission twice if it is denied two times in a row no more dialog will be displayed, you will have to go to the app settings to grant the permission.
